# Web Appbuilder consuming REST services without Web Map?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

How do you load REST Services into Web AppBuilder programmatically with the Map class?

What file within Web AppBuilder allows developers access to the map class/map object?

Basically, I want to pull in (consume) REST services into ESRI Web AppBuilder without a pre-configured web map.

Comment: Have you looked into developing a [custom widget that accesses the map](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/access-a-map.htm)?

Comment: I am fairly new to Web Appbuilder.  Someone told me, If you want to add layer into the map at app startup then put your code in the widget that is configured as  "WidgetOnScreen". and put your code to add layer in widget's postCreate or startup function. (can also specify the layer url in the widgets config). Every widget inherited from "jimu/BaseWidget" does have reference to the map object. You can simply add any layer into this. Is this a supported work flow within Web Appbuilder?

Comment: Yes. Have you downloaded the Web Appbuilder (WAB) Developer Edition?  It has examples to get you started. https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/create-custom-in-panel-widget.htm

Comment: Yes, Kirk I have downloaded Web Appbuilder (WAB) developer edition, and I have used it to create out the web apps without any custom coding in the past.  For this project I want to consume REST services via a web map (via Portal) and also consume REST services directly into the map (as done in the JS API).  I am having trouble identifying the correct file that I need to apply the custom code to within web app builder to accomplish my tasks of consuming REST services from multiple sources.  I think I want write my custom code within the config.Json. Can you confirm this is correct?

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this : https://github.com/cmndrbensisko/LocalLayer/releases/tag/v2.0

Give it a try

More Info:

The LocalLayer Widget for ArcGIS Web AppBuilder is intended to allow the direct addition of ArcGIS for Server Mapservices to an ArcGIS Web AppBuilder application, without needing to wrap the desired services in an ArcGIS Online/Portal Web Map. See how to use and deploy the widget here

https://github.com/cmndrbensisko/LocalLayer

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [Tour].  Links can change or disappear without warning - please [edit] your answer to include more information about the steps required and explain how this answers the question